# How to save vue3openlayer coords to Django SRID4326

Tags: django, vue.js, geospatial

I am trying to make markers in my OpenStreetMap. Currently one building in the Bangkok when I use Django coordinate it shows.
`"SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT (100.53007692708017 13.721325314629256)"`
Then I make my own Vue3 to be a marker. My function to get the coordinates is
`template`

```
 <ol-map
    :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true"
    :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true"
    style="height: 400px"
    @click="handleMapClick"
  >
    <ol-view
      ref="view"
      :center="center"
      :rotation="rotation"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :projection="projection"
    />

    <ol-tile-layer>
      <ol-source-osm/>
    </ol-tile-layer>
  </ol-map>
```

`script`

```
import { fromLonLat, toLonLat } from 'ol/proj'; // Import fromLonLat and toLonLat
    const convertToSRID4326 = (coordinates) => {
      const latitude = coordinates[0];
      const longitude = coordinates[1];

      const latitudeInDegrees = latitude * (180 / Math.PI);
      const longitudeInDegrees = longitude * (180 / Math.PI);

      return { latitude: latitudeInDegrees, longitude: longitudeInDegrees };
    }

    const handleMapClick = (event) => {
      const clickedCoords = toLonLat(event.coordinate);
      markers.value.push(clickedCoords)
      markers.value.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        console.log(convertToSRID4326(element))
      })
    }
```

My widget:  `{0: 0.0009030769278815491, 1: 0.00012325954951108997}`
My conversion: `latitude: 0.05174249654325298 longitude: 0.007062251971669265`

But Django is:
`"SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT (100.53007692708017 13.721325314629256)"`

**Goal:**
Vue3 be able to use same SRID:4326 as Django.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to put fancy staff. I just need `console.log(event.coordinate)`. And that is!